# Cannot get GET: api/xyz to work with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table a with a foreign key to another table b. The EF model was generated from the database. What I want is just all the data from the table a.

But the auto-generated method

```
        // GET: api/Massnahmentyp
        public IQueryable<MASSNAHMENTYP> GetMASSNAHMENTYPs()
        {
            return db.MASSNAHMENTYPs;
        }
```

returns nothing. However, the method

```
        // GET: api/Massnahmentyp/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(MASSNAHMENTYP))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMASSNAHMENTYP(decimal id)
        {
            MASSNAHMENTYP mASSNAHMENTYP = db.MASSNAHMENTYPs.Find(id);
            if (mASSNAHMENTYP == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(mASSNAHMENTYP);
        }
```

works and returns the correct entry. What do I do wrong?

**Update**
Ok, it seems that it worked all the time, just the response was way to big because of the foreign key. Is it possible to ignore the dependencies, so that it does not join thousands of entries into the response? Table a has only 6 entries and I only want them.

Comment: Have you tried to return db.MASSNAHMENTYPs.ToList(); and set the method output type to List or IEnumerable ?

Comment: _"Is it possible to ignore the dependencies"_ - yeah, by disabling lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about following code?

```
// GET: api/Massnahmentyp
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<MASSNAHMENTYP> GetMASSNAHMENTYPs()
{
    return db.MASSNAHMENTYPs.ToList();
}
```

I think you should annotate your method with `[HttpGet]`.

**Update**: For the new part of your question:

You can disable lazy loading in DbContext:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public YourContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```